# Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup. usageLimits exceeded

Tags: google-plus, google-drive-realtime-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-apis-explorer

What does it mean?  I have used following scopes for accessing google drive.

```
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
```

when I see in my console, it is showing errors ,

> code: 403,
>    domain: 'usageLimits',
>    reason: 'dailyLimitExceededUnreg',
>    message: 'Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded.
>    }

What am I doing wrong ? However, I have changed my domain from http://localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3003 and all credentials also.

I didn't get any correct answer. please anyone help me.

Comment: You probably exceeded your unauthenticated use rate limits.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code.   We cant help you fix your issue without seeing your code.   The problem is that you are trying to access private data and have not properly authenticated.    You need an access token